# Create circles of varying radii based on an attribute using PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I was wondering if it is possible to write a SQL statement to create circles for each point of a layer, such that the radius of each circle is determined by an attribute of the point geometry it centers on?

I looked around , and answers to creating circles all point to `ST_Buffer` and take a fixed radius as parameter, which do not fit my need.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, as geoandri already pointed out, you can do that by using a subquery:

SELECT ST_Buffer((select the_geom from point), (select radius-field from point));

You might have to include where-statements that make sure you only buffer one point.
But there also might be more complex queries that could fit your needs better. 

If so, provide more intel on your table and I could come up with a working query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field as radius to ST_Buffer.

```
  SELECT ST_Buffer(the_geom,cast(field_to_be_used_as_radius as float)) from table;
```

The above works fine for me.